# java method returning null value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In doing a project using Spring MVC. The basic is: when a student signs up, his data will be stored in the database table and the password will be sent to the students mail address.

So I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String dosignup(@Valid @ModelAttribute("student") Student student, HttpServletRequest request,
  HttpServletResponse response, BindingResult result) {

    studentService.addNewStudent(student.getName(),
        student.getUsername(), student.getEmail(), student.getPassword());
    studentService.sendEmail(student);
}
```

`StudentDao` interface is:

```
public interface StudentDao {
    public void saveStudent(Student student);
    public void fetchinfo(Student student);
}
```

`fetchinfo` implementation in `StudentDaoImpl` is:

```
public void fetchinfo(Student student) {
    String hql = "select password from student where email = :email";
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql)
        .setParameter("email", student.getEmail()).uniqueResult();
}
```

`StudentService` interface is:

```
public interface StudentService {
    Student addNewStudent(String name, String username, String email, String password);
    void sendEmail(Student student);
    Student fetchinfo(String email);
}
```

and `StudentServiceImpl` is:

```
public User fetchinfo(String email) {
    Student student = new Student(email);
    studentDao.fetchinfo(student);
    return student;
}

public void sendEmail(Student student) {
    mailService.accountActivation(student);
}
```

Now, the problem is: a mail is sent to the students mail address, but the password is `null`. Can someone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `StudentDaoImpl` you are not setting the password property from the db query result. Rewrite relevant line as:

```
student.setPassword(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql)
    .setParameter("email", student.getEmail()).uniqueResult());
```

**Update**

While we are in Hibernate, by convention Student entity should have getters and setters for each property. Then I would rewrite `StudentDaoImpl` as:

```
public void fetchinfo(String email) {

    String hql = "select s from student s where s.email = :email";

    return (Student)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(hql)
      .setParameter("email", email).uniqueResult();

}
```

..and call it with `student = studentDao.fetchinfo(email);` (of course naming of methods should change).

Comment: I dont have set the password field as object..why I will use that?

Comment: my UserDao, I have   " public void fetchUserinfo(User user);"..then I have to edit this field also..am I r8?

Comment: I have used your code..it is showing the errror:-- java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.news.Student